# JavaScript lint doesn't recognize embedded PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I am using JavaScript Lint in vim. Recently I converted my pure JavaScript to php so as to make certain server side additions. I have set the file type in vim as such `:s filetype=javascript.php`.

test.php:

```
/*jsl:ignore*/
<?php
  header("Content-type: application/x-javascript");
?>
/*jsl:end*/

function foo() {...}
```

I get a syntax error at `<?php`, both in vim and [online](http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php). I guess `jsl:ignore` ignores warnings, but not syntax errors, and it is detecting `<?php` as a syntax error. Is there anyway to bypass this as it is essentially a deal breaker for JavaScript Lint.

---

**EDIT** There have been a great number of requests as to what it is I am doing, therefore, here is a more thorough explanation.

I have a database for my pictures, like so

```
ID owner path
0  0     /var/www/0/*.jpg
1  0     /var/www/0/*.jpg
2  1     /var/www/1/*.jpg
3  2     /var/www/2/*.jpg
4  0     /var/www/0/*.jpg
```

The important thing here is that there is absolutely no correlation between the picture ID and/or who owns the picture and/or where the picture is stored. The client **must** query the database to find out where the files are stored (the reason for this is that user pictures are added in arbitrary order, and they are often moved around). Lets say there are 1000 pictures, and I want to load them all into the browser (tiny thumbnails).

I could load up `index.html` then use Ajax to get all 1000 file locations and set populate the browser with images somewhat like so

```
for (var i = ; i < picturePaths.length ;i++){
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = picturePaths[i];
}
```

But I don't want to use Ajax because it is very slow (3/4s) to kick in and retrieve any queries. Instead I want all the `img.src` attributes to already be set when the page loads.

Now John Watson mentioned [below](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8231148/654789) that I could/should return all of these in a single variable and reference that. I am not an expert so he could be right. However, My website is very complex, and different scripts are being dynamically loaded from the server quite frequently, I would prefer not to store important image path's in a single global object.

Comment: what's the point in these comments, `/*jsl:ignore*/`?

Comment: Why would you have php header function inside javascript anyways?

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel `/*jsl:ignore*/` tells JavascriptLint to 'ignore' everything between it and `/*jsl:end*/` It's for things that aren't errors but still dangerous, like `var i += ++j`

Comment: @Catfish `foo()` fetches image file names from the server (database). I want my php script to pass that image file name to `foo()` so it doesn't later have to make an AJAX request.

Comment: ...at the same time it tell the browser to start output and thus PHP cannot send the header

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel we might be talking about different things. `/*jsl:ignore*/` is for vim, the browser just ignores it as a comment [see here](http://www.javascriptlint.com/docs/index.htm)

Comment: oh, my bad. it tells *PHP* to start output, not browser. what a silly of me.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel you lost me again, what "tells PHP to start output"? The `<?php header(...)?>` line or `/*jsl:ignore*/`

Comment: @puk if possible, you don't want anything outside of your `<?php` tags that could be interpreted as content as headers can only be set BEFORE content is output - I don't know if this will happen in your case above, but this is waht Col. Shrapnel is alluding to. Your can no longer set a header once you've written actual output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution for this issue would be to separate my PHP and JavaScript where possible.

Let your PHP output whatever it needs to output into your HTML and then pick it up from your JavaScript if you want to use it. I can give you more concrete examples of this if you show us what you're doing.

Dynamically spitting out a JavaScript file can be problematic as it will be cached on the browser, so the second and subsequent requests may not come back to the server to get a re-evaluated script file.

Comment: I didn't know it could get cached. That would be a serious problem. What I have in mind is loading multiple images from a database. Rather than query the database for the image path, I want the server to update `image.src` when giving the page back

Answer (score 1):

I assume you've got javascript in your code that looks something like this:

```
var data = '<?php echo $some_value ?>';
```

A better way to deal with this is to use PHP to emit vars for all of the data your script will need somewhere in the header before your main Javascript file is included. So, your PHP code would create something like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var MyNamespace = {
            data1: "value1",
            data2: "value2"
    };
    </script>
```

And then include your javascript file like normal as a pure Javascript file without any of the PHP:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="my-actual-script.js">
```

Then, in this example, you can use MyNamespace in your javascript like:

```
    var data = MyNamespace.data;
```

Comment: He doesn't have the `var data = '<?php'` problem (but your second point still holds though).

Comment: That wasn't clear to me from the question... if he doesn't then there is no reason at all to make the javascript a .php file in the first place.

Comment: He can do it to insert variables or do "preprocessor" if-deffing. I'm not saying its a best practice or anything but it at least makes sense

Comment: @missingno sorry, I didn't go into detail b/c I assumed there was a simple answer to fix JavascriptLint. The reality is that I have scripts on the server that get loaded dynamically, and they in turn link to other files to load, each acting as its own self contained module. It just felt natural to modify each 'module' individually serverside before giving it to the client.

Comment: @puk: If you are just using this php to do module magic you should look into using a real module system like requireJS. It manages dependencies better, lets you compile everything in a single file for production and lots of other goodies.

Comment: @missingno I looked at requireJS but built my own module loader because I needed more control. Out of curiosity, how would requireJS help with this PHP related issue?

Comment: @puk: by getting rid of the PHP :)

Comment: @missingno LOL what I meant is that I am not using this PHP approach to load the modules. I was merely using it 'fill in the gaps' serverside